# Question instead of simple sentence

Tags: questions, cinema

In a movie, when adults adore children, they used to ask question instead of a simple sentence. For instance, normally one would say

> You're so sweet.

But they said

> Oh, aren't you sweet?

which is weird. When would someone ask a question for such constructions?

Comment: Generally this is used rhetorically. I say quite frequently: "Man, am I stupid or what?", or, sarcastically, "Oh, isn't that just *fantastic*?".

Comment: @Ledda: Right, but saying "isn't she sweet?" when referring to an adorable child is not as weird as "aren't you sweet?".

Comment: I feel that it's perfectly fine to address someone directly with that construction. I would say to a gorgeous girl, perhaps, "Wow! Don't you just look *gorgeous*!", for example. I'm not even sure if it's the interrogative mood. It's constructed the same way but it semantically feels like an exclamation.

Comment: You're confusing the meaning. *Are you not sweet?* Stress on the word, "not" might be interpreted as asking whether a person is pleasant or not. In your example however, it is as Ledda correctly pointed out, a rhetorical question. We already know the answer. "Of course she is sweet!" It's like when a small boy compliments himself by saying "Aren't (or ain't) I a clever/good/smart little boy!"

Answer (score 1):

When someone questions a child

> Oh, aren't you sweet?

the most obvious answer, "Yes, I am a sweet child" is taken as a given. No one expects a negative response. It's just another way of flattering or complimenting someone, without being considered too forward.

If I am with a group of girlfriends and we see a hunk of a man walking down the street I might whisper to them

> Oh my God, isn't he *gorgeous*?!

His gorgeousness is plain to see, I don't expect anyone to contradict my judgement. I am, in a way, stating a fact.

This type of rhetorical question might be argued to be a simplified form of 
[**hypophora**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophora), also called **anthypophora**,
(*ant-hi-POF-era* or *an-thi-PO-for-a*). It is a figure of speech in which the speaker poses a question and then immediately answers one's own questions. A type of reasoning aloud.

An example of anthypophora is the following by Winston Churchill

> "You ask, what is our aim? I can answer in one word: Victory. Victory
>   at all costs, victory in spite of all terror; victory, however long
>   and hard the road may be, for without victory, there is no survival."

[Source](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Anthypophora.htm)

Another closely related term is **ratiocinatio**  (*ra'-ti-o-cin-a'-ti-o*)

> Reasoning (typically with oneself) by asking questions.

[The Forest of Rhetoric](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/R/ratiocinatio.htm)

However, in the realm of English grammar this type of negative question is called **Negative Polar Interrogatives**

> "Negative yes-no interrogatives are typically used to ask questions
>   which function to check or confirm something which the speaker
>   believes or expects to be the case, or which the speaker considers to
>   be a viable course of action.
>
> "The negative is formed with not, and is most frequently contracted to
>   n't. Sentences with the full form are not more formal than those with
>   contracted n't:
>
> ```
> Wasn't he here at the party?
> Don't you want any tea or coffee?
> ```
>
> Where the full form is used, not comes after the subject:
>
> ```
> Could you not hear me?
> (please confirm, yes or no)
> Should we not photocopy it?
> (I consider this a desirable action)
> ```

[Interrogative sentence](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/interrogterm.htm)